# how to fix Unknown error in my emulator when running react native project

Tags: react-native

How to fix Unknown error in my emulator when running react native project?

My project was good 2 minutes ago.

but I run it again, and i get this error in my emulator

[image]

Comment: what you have tried

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when sharing code or error messages. And if you share a screenshot, crop it to leave irrelevant information behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix my error
and i had a mistake from in my file( just would put a "," in my file)
thanks